# List of dicts: remove duplicates and stack together unique values

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a list similar to this:

```
[
    {'code': 'ABCDEFGH',
     'message':'Everything is not OK',
     'name': 'Tom Sawyer',
     'course': 'Networks'},

    {'code': 'ABCDEFGH',
     'message':'Alright',
     'name': 'Julien Sorel',
     'course': 'Networks'},

    {'code': 'KQPRADBC',
     'message':'Hello there',
     'name': 'Jacques Paganel',
     'course': 'Cooking'},

    {'code': 'KQPRADBC',
     'message':'Hello there',
     'name': 'Jacques Paganel',
     'course': 'Cooking'},
]
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
[
    {'code': 'ABCDEFGH',
     'message': ['Everything is not OK', 'Alright'],
     'name': ['Tom Sawyer', 'Julien Sorel'],
     'course': 'Networks'},

    {'code': 'KQPRADBC',
     'message':'Hello there',
     'name': 'Jacques Paganel',
     'course': 'Cooking'},
]
```

So that fully duplicate entries would be removed and those, which have unique dictionary values, would be merged in a list. The order is not important.

This looks like a huge hack for me. Thanks in advance.

***! Python 3.5 !***

Comment: I think the solution would be to write a loop which builds another dict. The loop would need to look at the "code" field, determine if it is unique or not in the new dict, and then add appropriately (i.e. comparing other columns where necessary).

Comment: Show the code you have written, and your results.  What is or isn't working?

Comment: @joelgoldstick Needed a general idea on how to try this out (I thought this should work through deleting) and Brandon gave me. I'll try this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To guarantee unicity with rather simple readable code, one could use sets. See comments in the code.

I suggest, supposing `lst` contains your list of dictionaries :

```
res = list()  # start from scratch
for k in lst:
    for d in res:  # check the previously created entries
        if d['code'] == k['code']:
            # add to entry
            for field in ['message', 'name', 'course']:
                d[field].add(k[field])  # will not do anything if value is already here
            break
    else:  # this will be executed if the for didn't break
        # create new entry
        tmp = {'code': k['code']}
        for field in ['message', 'name', 'course']:
            tmp[field] = set([k[field]])
        res.append(tmp)
print res
```

With your list of dictionaries as entry, I get the following:

```
[
{'course': set(['Networks']),
'message': set(['Alright', 'Everything is not OK']),
'code': 'ABCDEFGH',
'name': set(['Julien Sorel', 'Tom Sawyer'])},

{'course': set(['Cooking']),
'message': set(['Hello there']),
'code': 'KQPRADBC',
'name': set(['Jacques Paganel'])}
]
```

If you want to have exactly the same output as you wrote in your question, you might want to add somthing like this at the end:

```
for d in res:
    for field in ['message', 'name', 'course']:
        if len(d[field]) > 1:
            d[field] = list(d[field])
        else:
            d[field] = list(d[field])[0]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. There's a little indentation issue with `else`.

Comment: Nope. It's meant to be on the same vertical line than the `for` ;) See [this](http://psung.blogspot.com/2007/12/for-else-in-python.html) for further enlightenment

Comment: Oh. I wll cite one of the commenters there: `wow, I never knew this`!

Comment: Yeah, blew my mind too when I learnt this. And hey, since it's just you and me here, I learnt it in [this](https://youtu.be/OSGv2VnC0go) video from [Raymond Hettinger](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1001643/raymond-hettinger) himself ;)

Comment: Thanks for the provided video. It's definitely about time to learn some python :D

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [
{'code': 'ABCDEFGH',
 'message':'Everything is not OK',
 'name': 'Tom Sawyer',
 'course': 'Networks'},

{'code': 'ABCDEFGH',
 'message':'Alright',
 'name': 'Julien Sorel',
 'course': 'Networks'},

{'code': 'KQPRADBC',
 'message':'Hello there',
 'name': 'Jacques Paganel',
 'course': 'Cooking'},

{'code': 'KQPRADBC',
 'message':'Hello there',
 'name': 'Jacques Paganel',
 'course': 'Cooking'},
]
out=[]
for i in set([tuple(d.items()) for d in a]):
    out.append(dict(i))
print out
```

**output:**

```
[{'course': 'Cooking', 'message': 'Hello there', 'code': 'KQPRADBC', 'name': 'Jacques Paganel'},
{'course': 'Networks', 'message': 'Everything is not OK', 'code': 'ABCDEFGH', 'name': 'Tom Sawyer'},
{'course': 'Networks', 'message': 'Alright', 'code': 'ABCDEFGH', 'name': 'Julien Sorel'}]
```